# How do I add a custom field to a Sitefinity widget?

Tags: sitefinity

I am trying to add a related image field in the news component that is provided by Sitefinity. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Administration > Module Builder under the tools section of the dropdown.  Scroll down to News Items and select it. Once inside it you will want to click on the news items under the modules contains header. From there you can scroll down and select: add a field. Select type related media and you can name it and set certain settings like if it is required.